# javascript not working on form

Tags: javascript

can someone tell me why the script in the header tag doesn't work. I can get the form to show up, enter all of my information, click submit but i don't get the output to show up. I've looked at the code over and over but don't see what the problem is. I would greatly appreciate some help. My teacher at school doesn't help much.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Event Scheduler
</title>

</head>
<body>
<header>
<script>
    function scheduledEvent(evtdate, evtTitle, maxattendees, coordinator,        phonenum, email, infourl, printEvent)
    {
        this.evtdate = evtdate;
        this.evttitle = evtTitle;
        this.maxattendees = maxattendees;
        this.coordinator = coordinator;
        this.phonenum = phonenum;
        this.email = email;
        this.infourl = infourl;
        this.printEvent = printEvent;

        function printEvent()
        {
            document.write("<p>You have scheduled an event named " +   this.evtTitle);
            document.write(" that will occur on " + this.evtdate + " and allow up to " + this.maxattendees + " attendees.");
            document.write("The event is coordinated by " + this.coordinator + " who can be reached at " + this.phonenum);
            document.write(" or by email at " + this.email + ". ");
            document.write("More information about the event is available at  <a href= '" + this.infourl + "'> " + this.infourl + "</a></p>");
            }
        function validate() 
        {
            with (document.evtForm) 
            {

            evt = new ScheduledEvent(evtDate.value, evtTitle.value, maxattendees.value, evtCoordinator.value, phonenum.value, email.value, infourl.value);
            }

            with (evt)
            {
                evt.printEvent();
            }

            return true;
        }
</script>

</header>
<form name= "evtForm" method= "post">
<table>

<tr>
<td>
Event Date: </td><td><input type= date id= "evtDate" /></td></td>

<tr><td>Title:</td><td><input id= "evtTitle" /></td></tr>

<tr><td>
Maximum attendees: </td><td><input id= "evtCoordinator" /><td></tr>

<tr><td>
Phone number (numbers only): </td><td><input type= tel id= "phonenum" />     </td></tr>

<tr><td>
Email: </td><td><input type= email id= "email" /></td></tr>



<tr><td> 
More info: </td><td><input type= url id= "infourl" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type= submit value= "Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a right brace at the end of your JavaScript.  Also, learn to work with the browser console and inspectors - press F12.  It will show you the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well your input fields are ALL missing quotations arround your name attributes.

You have:

```
<input type= date id= "evtDate" />
```

When you should have:

```
<input type="date" id="evtDate" />
```

You are also not even doing anything on click of the submit button.

You need to start the function somehow in a click method or something. You seem to expect it to magically start working.

Comment: no i'm not expecting any magic. i'm just starting out learning javascript and java. gets a little confusing starting out. Especially when the book tells me to do it like i did. thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Event Scheduler
</title>

</head>
<body>
<header>
<script>
    function scheduledEvent(evtdate, evtTitle, maxattendees, coordinator,        phonenum, email, infourl, printEvent)
    {
        this.evtdate = evtdate;
        this.evttitle = evtTitle;
        this.maxattendees = maxattendees;
        this.coordinator = coordinator;
        this.phonenum = phonenum;
        this.email = email;
        this.infourl = infourl;
        this.printEvent = printEvent;

        function printEvent()
        {
            document.write("<p>You have scheduled an event named " +   this.evtTitle);
            document.write(" that will occur on " + this.evtdate + " and allow up to " + this.maxattendees + " attendees.");
            document.write("The event is coordinated by " + this.coordinator + " who can be reached at " + this.phonenum);
            document.write(" or by email at " + this.email + ". ");
            document.write("More information about the event is available at  <a href= '" + this.infourl + "'> " + this.infourl + "</a></p>");
            }
        function validate() 
        {
            with (document.evtForm) 
            {

            evt = new ScheduledEvent(evtDate.value, evtTitle.value, maxattendees.value, evtCoordinator.value, phonenum.value, email.value, infourl.value);
            }

            with (evt)
            {
                evt.printEvent();
            }

            return true;
        }
</script>

</header>
<form name= "evtForm" method= "post">
<table>

<tr>
<td>
Event Date: </td><td><input type= date id= "evtDate" name="evtDate" /></td></td>

<tr><td>Title:</td><td><input id= "evtTitle" name="evtTitle" /></td></tr>

<tr><td>
Maximum attendees: </td><td><input id= "evtCoordinator" name="evtCoordinator" /><td></tr>

<tr><td>
Phone number (numbers only): </td><td><input type= tel id= "phonenum" name="phonenum" />     </td></tr>

<tr><td>
Email: </td><td><input type= email id= "email" name="email" /></td></tr>



<tr><td> 
More info: </td><td><input type= url id= "infourl" name="infourl" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type= submit value= "Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or just a test post?